# Problem with add attr to img and set path

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem becouse I read values of labels and after that i want to set img src dependent on value label

Here some code and i see that is img attr don't add

getState generate divs with content

At the end is ajax call function where i get values from database and write them to the dynamically generated labels

The main problem now is then that don't read a values of labels correct becouse I got 3 labels with 3 diffrent states like "Active","Standby","Error" and it set for all Emergency Stop icon

```
 function ChangeImage() {
         let labels = $('label[data-id]');
         $.each(labels, function (i, x) {
             var states = $(x).text();
             console.log(states);
             if (states == "Active") {
                 var Active = "Images/kafle/zebatakActive.svg";
                 $(this).closest('img').attr("src", Active);
             } else if (states == "Standby") {
                 var Standby = "Images/kafle/kafle_zebatka-01.svg"
                 $(this).closest('img').attr("src", Standby);
             } else if (states == "Error") {
                 var error = "Images/kafle/kafle_zebatka-01.svg";
                 $(this).closest('img').attr("src", error);
             } else if (states == "Setting") {
                 var Settings = "Images/kafel/kafle_zebatka-03.svg"
                 $(this).closest('img').attr("src", Settings);
             } else {
                 var Emergency = "Images/kafle/kafle_status-yel-yel.svg";
                 $(this).closest('img').attr("src", Emergency);
             }
         });
     }

 function getState() {
         try {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "Default.aspx/jsrequest",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (data) {
                     $("#ajax").empty();
                     $.each(data, function () {
                         $("#ajax").append('<div id="ajaxcontent"></div>');
                         $("#ajaxcontent").addClass("ajaxcontent");
                         $.each(this, function (k,v) {
                             $("#ajaxcontent").append('<div class="view">' + ' <label id="IdOfMachine">' + v.MachineId + '</label>'
                                 + '<label class="MachineState" name="Values" data-id= "' + v.MachineId + ' " > ' + v.CurrentStatus + '</label > '
                                 + '<img class="ChangeImg" data-id="' + v.MachineId + '"> ' + '</img > '
                                 + '<label id="MachineName">' + v.MachineName + '</label>' + '</div>');
                         });
                     });
                 },
                 error: function (response) {
                     alert("cos źle")
                 }
             });
         } catch (err) { }
     }

 public static List<StateOfMachine> jsrequest()
    {
        List<StateOfMachine> MachineState = new List<StateOfMachine>();
        string DBInfo = @"Data Source=STACJA45;Initial Catalog=AutoRefresh;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
        string sqlrequest = "Select MachineID,CurrentStatus,MachineName from MachineStates";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBInfo);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlrequest, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader DataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (DataReader.Read()) {
            StateOfMachine machines = new StateOfMachine();
            machines.MachineId = DataReader["MachineID"].ToString();
            machines.MachineName = DataReader["MachineName"].ToString();
            machines.CurrentStatus = DataReader["CurrentStatus"].ToString();

            MachineState.Add(machines);
        }
        DataReader.Close();
        command.Dispose();
        connection.Close();
        return MachineState;

    }
```

Comment: provide html code here

Comment: @DevsiOdedra One second

Comment: check what is $(this) i think is it window ?

Comment: try .find('img') instead of closest('img')

Comment: @Przeklin You have to use `$(this).next('img').attr("src", Emergency);`

Answer (score 4):

first of all, **welcome to StackOverflow :)**

2 things in your code to avoid in the future:

- DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself - every time you're writing the same thing over and over, you're doing it wrong :)
- To be precise, always use `===` instead of `==` the later will give `true` for `1 == "1"` and it's better to avoid it since the start.

Relating to your issue, apart for repeating yourself and the use of `==` you are specifying `$(this)` and that is ok as long as you pass a jQuery event because it's a self function, the object `this` is not what you are assuming.

your code could be changed to something as:

```
function ChangeImage() {
     var labels = $('label[data-id]');
     $.each(labels, function (i, x) {
         var url = '';
         var path = 'Images/kafle';
         var state = $(x).text();

         switch(state) {
             case "Active": url = path + "/zebatakActive.svg"; break;
             case "Standby": url = path + "/kafle_zebatka-01.svg"; break;
             case "Error": url = path + "/kafle_zebatka-01.svg"; break;
             case "Setting": url = path + "/kafle_zebatka-03.svg"; break;
             default: url = path + "/kafle_status-yel-yel.svg"; break;
         }
         $('img[data-id="' + state + '"]').attr("src", url);

         console.log({path, state, url});
     });
 }
```

*code edited* from comments

Comment: Nice answer, just a note, it should be `$(x).next('img')` since the image is a sibling of the label in the `.each`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen tusind tak :) I didn't saw it in teh code when I started the answer :)

Comment: No problem, we are here to help each other.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it's works but not as I want becouse for example label1 have value "Active", label2 "Standby" and if call ChangeImage() it's set Active for all labels

Comment: @balexandre it's set default for all labels with values "Standby" and etc

Comment: @Przeklin what does your `console.log` outputs per each label? just change to it ... maybe it's all lowercase?

Comment: @balexandre now i got 4 lables with values 1."Active" 2.Standby 3.Error 4.Active if I call function in console they outputs actually state of label and undefined then set last icon for all label's

Comment: @Przeklin check out the image url, i've added `kafle_zebatka-02.svg` but originally you have the same image url as `Standby`... and to make sure you have the right path, add a `<img src="Images/kafle/zebatakActive.svg" />` to your document so you see if it picks the right image

Comment: @balexandre path is correct becouse if I add <img> in document display current image from  path

Comment: @Przeklin go to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198580/57686881-problem-with-add-attr-to-img-and-set-path

Comment: @balexandre I don't have enough reputation :\

Comment: @Przeklin to create a room no, but to write on the chat? ... I've given you 15 more points though :) so you have now, more than the [minimum **20**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat)

Comment: @balexandre thanks and I find solutions, just change $(x).next('img').attr("src",url) to $('img[data-id="'+i+'"]').attr("src", Active); and it works at end thanks one more time for help <3

Answer (score 1):

remove **closet()** and put **find()**

```js
function ChangeImage() {
         let labels = $('label[data-id]');
         $.each(labels, function (i, x) {
             var states = $(x).text();
             switch(states)
             {
             case "Active":
                $(this).find('img').attr("src","Images/kafle/zebatakActive.svg");
                break;
             case "Standby":
                $(this).find('img').attr("src", "Images/kafle/kafle_zebatka-01.svg");
                break;
             case "Error":
                $(this).find('img').attr("src",  "Images/kafle/kafle_zebatka-01.svg");
                break;
              case "Setting":
                $(this).find('img').attr("src",  "Images/kafel/kafle_zebatka-03.svg");
                break;
              default:
                $(this).find('img').attr("src", "Images/kafle/kafle_status-yel-yel.svg");
                break;
             }
         });
     }
```

Comment: it's not working for me, after call function don't add src attr :\

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

If you are using HTML as in the following code snippet, you can use siblings([selector]) to read the matching sibling element and to change the src of the image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div>
  <img src="#" class="image" height="100" width="100">
  <label data-id="1" class="image-link">Active</label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <img src="#" class="image" height="100" width="100">
  <label data-id="2" class="image-link">Emergency</label>
 </div>

<button onclick="changeImage()">Change</button>


<script>
function changeImage() {
         let labels = $('label[data-id]');
         $.each(labels, function (i, x) {
             var states = $(x).text();
             if (states == "Active") {
                 var Active = "https://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/golden-soccer-ball-3yLR9z1-600.jpg";
                 $(this).siblings('img').attr( {"src": Active });
             } else {
                 var Emergency = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png";
                 $(this).siblings('img').attr("src", Emergency);
             }
         });
     }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's worked but not as i want becouse it's set image dependent of first label to another labels. For example my first label have value "Active" and second label have "Standby" and it set Active img to both.

Comment: Can you provide your sample **ajax data** or **HTML template**, so that I could check.

Comment: Can you look now at that ?